# PHP / MySQL - Compare tables from 2 different databases

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance, compare

I've got 2 frameworks (Laravel - web, Codeigniter - API) and 2 different databases. I've built a function (on the API) which detect changes on one database (from 2 tables) and apply the changes in the other database.

Note: there is no way to run both web and API on the same databases - so thats why I'm doing this thing.

Anyway, this is important that every little change will recognized. If the case is new record or delete record - its simple and no problem at all. But, if the records exists in both databases - I need to compare their values to detect changes and this section become challenging.

I know how to do this in the slowest and heavy way (pick each record and compare).

**My question is - how do you suggest to make it work in smart and fast way?**

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the mysql user has select rights on both databases, you can qualify the database in the query like so:

```
SELECT * FROM `db1`.`table1`;
SELECT * FROM `db2`.`table1`;
```

It doesn't matter which database has been selected when you connected to PHP. The correct database will be used in the query.

The ticks are optional when the database/table name is only alphanumeric and not an SQL keyword.

Comment: For security and performance reasons, the SQL user doesn't rights on both databases. I'm working with heavy websites which work together with API.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the response-time of the 'slave'-database there are a two options which don't increase the overhead too much:

1. If you can combine both databases within the same database by prefixing one or both of the tables, you can use `FOREIGN KEYS` to let the database do the tough work for you.
2. Use the `TIMESTAMP`-field which you can set to update itself by the DB whenever the row gets updated.

Option 1 would be my best guess, but that might mean a physical change to the running system, and if `FOREIGN KEYS` are new for you, you might wanna test since they can be a real PITA (IMHO).

Option 2 is easier to implement, but you still have to manually detect changes to deleted/rows.